# Error (ssh-agency): ‘/usr/bin/ssh-add’ failed with status 1:

Tags: magit

(I am using MAC OS High Sierra v.10.13.6) with Emacs v26.1

When attempting to push changes to a remote-repo (Github) using the package magit

I received the following error in the buffer.

```
Error (ssh-agency): ‘/usr/bin/ssh-add’ failed with status 1:
```

Comment: As far as I understand, the error is due to you not having any ssh keys.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue by doing the following:

1. created a .ssh folder in Home (default directory in terminal)
2. I then followed the following instructions https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

3.I then added the new public SSH key to Github by following these instructions https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/

4. I tested the SSH connection using `ssh -T git@github.com` (for more info see https://help.github.com/articles/testing-your-ssh-connection/)
5. I then needed to switch over my existing remote repos to use SSH instead of HTTPS which i did using the instructions here: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/#switching-remote-urls-from-https-to-ssh
6. I tested with `git remote -v`

I could now see that it had changed over from HTTPS to SSH by observing the output as:

origin  git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (push)

7. I went into emacs and made some changes to a file within the local git repo and did `M-x m-stat [ret]` and then `C-c C-c` then pushed the changes via the quick menu in magit and voila all is now working without any errors.

Restarted laptop to be sure and all is great.

I am sure there would have been an option for ssh passphrase auth using the github HTTPS origin but I didn't want to mess around with adding a passphrase into keychain and then adding this into the ssh-agent.

Comment: "an option for HTTPS auth [...] adding a password into keychain and then adding this into the ssh-agency." - ssh-agency only deals with ssh-agent, so you cannot add HTTPS passwords to it.

Comment: @npostavs your right sorry I meant ssh-agent. I have edited the answer to reflect.

Comment: I think in this case it makes no difference, ssh-agent only takes ssh keys, it can't handle HTTPS authentication (and git wouldn't call it in that case anyway).

Comment: @npostavs your right again. My mistake. I was getting confused with SSH private key passphrases referred to here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48502/how-can-i-permanently-add-my-ssh-private-key-to-keychain-so-it-is-automatically